# Change the number of tick marks on a figure in R

Tags: r

I created a figure of two plots (two years) of climate data (temp and precip) that looks exactly like I want it, except that one of my axes has too many tick marks.  With everything I have going on with this figure, I can't find a way to specify fewer tick marks without messing up other parts.  I would also like to specify where the tick marks are.  Here is the figure: [image: Climate]

You can see that the tick marks for the top axis just blur together and the numbers chosen are not very meaningful to me.  How can I tell R what I really want?

Here are the datasets I am using:  [cobs10](https://www.dropbox.com/s/ysoiut7ma5y8q30/cobs10.txt) and
[cobs11](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/phonq4ssjv5dnb0/7iLelar0pR).

And here is my code:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.3)
plot(cobs10$day, cobs10$temp, type="l", col="red", yaxt="n", xlab="", ylab="",     
ylim=c(-25, 30))

axis(side=3, col="black", at=cobs10$day, labels=cobs10$gdd) 
at = axTicks(3)
mtext("Thermal Units", side=3, las=0, line = 3)

axis(side=2, col='red', labels=FALSE)
at= axTicks(2)
mtext(side=2, text= at, at = at, col = "red", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Temperature (C)", side=2, las=0, line=3)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$precip, type="h", col="blue", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="",     
xlab="")
axis(side=4, col='blue', labels=FALSE)
at = axTicks(4)
mtext(side = 4, text = at, at = at, col = "blue", line = 1,las=0)
mtext("Precipitation (cm)", side=4, las=0, line = 3)


par(mar = c(5,4,4,4) + 0.3)
plot(cobs11$day, cobs11$temp, type="l", col="red", yaxt="n", xlab="Day of Year",     
ylab="", ylim=c(-25, 30))

axis(side=3, col="black", at=cobs11$day, labels=cobs11$gdd) 
at = axTicks(3)
mtext("", side=3, las=0, line = 3)

axis(side=2, col='red', labels=FALSE)
at= axTicks(2)
mtext(side=2, text= at, at = at, col = "red", line = 1, las=0)
mtext("Temperature (C)", side=2, las=0, line=3)

par(new=TRUE)
plot(cobs11$gdd, cobs11$precip, type="h", col="blue", yaxt="n", xaxt="n", ylab="",     
xlab="", ylim=c(0,12))
axis(side=4, col='blue', labels=FALSE)
at = axTicks(4)
mtext(side = 4, text = at, at = at, col = "blue", line = 1,las=0)
mtext("Precipitation (cm)", side=4, las=0, line = 3)
```

Thanks for thinking about it.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You've pretty much got the solution already:

```
axis(side=3, col="black", at=cobs10$day, labels=cobs10$gdd)
```

Except, you are asking to have ticks and labels at every single entry.
Take a look at the function `pretty`:

```
at <- pretty(cobs10$day)
at
# [1]   0 100 200 300 400
```

These are where the ticks should be placed on the x-axis. Now you need to find the corresponding labels. This is not straigtforward, but we will get:

```
lbl <- which(cobs10$day %in% at)
lbl
# [1] 100 200 300
lbl <- c(0, cobs10$gdd[lbl]

axis(side=3, at=at[-5], labels=lbl)
```

---

**Update**

I've been a bit annoyed by your use of three different series in a single plot. There are many reasons this is troublesome.

1. Having two y-values are always troublesome see this article from [Stephen Few](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf) (go to page 5 for my favorite example); in your case it is not that serious due to the nature of the plots and your use of colours to indicate which y-axis the values belong to. But still, on principle.
2. Axis ticks should have a fixed function, e.g. linear or logarithm. With your Thermal Units, they appear "randomly" (I know that is not the case, but for an outsider they do).
3. We gotta do something about your x-axis ticks that just refer to "day of year".

First up, we take a look at your data and see what can be done naively. We recognize that your ''date'' variable is actual dates. Let's exploit it and make R aware of it!

```
cobs10 <- read.table('cobs10.txt',as.is=TRUE)
cobs10$date <- as.Date(cobs10$date)
plot(temp ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l')
```

[image: R's builtin plotting of a formula]

Here, I really like the x-axis ticks and had some trouble replicating it. ''pretty'' on dates insisted on either 4 ticks or 12 ticks. But we will come back to that later.

Next, we can do something about the overlay plotting. Here I use ''par(mfrow=c(3,1))'' to instruct R to have three multiple plots stacked in a single window; with these multiple plots we can differentiate between *inner* and *outer* margins. The ''mar'' and ''oma'' arguments refers to the *inner* and *outer* margin.

Lets put all three variable together!

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(0.6, 5.1, 0, 0.6), oma=c(5.1, 0, 1, 0))
plot(temp ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', ylab='Temperatur (C)')
plot(precip ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', ylab='Precipitation (cm)')
plot(gdd ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', ylab='Thermal units')
```

[image]

This looks okay, but not with ticks on top of the plots. Not good. Naturally, we can enable ticks in the first two plots (with ''plot(..., xaxt='n')''), but this will distort the bottom plot. So you will need to do so for all three plots and then add the axis to the *outer* plotting region.

```
par(mfrow=c(3,1), mar=c(0.6, 5.1, 0, 0.6), oma=c(5.1, 0, 1, 0))
plot(temp ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', xaxt='n', ylab='Temperatur (C)')
plot(precip ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', xaxt='n', ylab='Precipitation (cm)')
plot(gdd ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', xaxt='n', ylab='Thermal units')

ticks <- seq(from=min(cobs10$date), by='2 months', length=7)
lbl <- strftime(ticks, '%b')
axis(side=1, outer=TRUE, at=ticks, labels=lbl)
mtext('2010', side=1, outer=TRUE, line=3, cex=0.67)
```

[image]

Since ''pretty'' doesn't behave as we want it to, we use ''seq'' to make the sequence of x-axis ticks. Then we format the dates to just display an abbreviation of the month name, but this is done with regard to local settings (I live in Denmark), see ''locale''.
To add the axis-ticks and a label to the outer region, we must remember to specify ''outer=TRUE''; otherwise it is added to the last subplot.
Also note that I specified ''cex=0.67'' to match the font size of the x-axis to the y-axis.

Now I agree that displaying the thermal units in a individual subplot is not optimal, although it is the correct way of displaying it. But there was the issue with the ticks. What we really want is to display some nice values that clearly display that they are not linear. But your data does not necessarily contain these nice values, so we will have to interpolate them ourselves.
For this, I use the ''splinefun''

```
lbl <- c(0, 2, 200, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000)
thermals <-  splinefun(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$date)  # thermals is a function that returns the date (as an integer) for a requested value
thermals(lbl)
## [1] 14649.00 14686.79 14709.55 14761.28 14806.04 14847.68 14908.45
ticks <- as.Date(thermals(lbl), origin='1970-01-01') # remember to specify an origin when converting an integer to a Date.
```

Now the thermal ticks are in place, lets try it.

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), mar=c(0.6, 5.1, 0, 0.6), oma=c(5.1, 0, 4, 0))
plot(temp ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', xaxt='n', ylab='Temperatur (C)')
plot(precip ~ date, data=cobs10, type='l', xaxt='n', ylab='Precipitation (cm)')

usr <- par('usr')
x.pos <- (usr[2]+usr[1])/2

ticks <- seq(from=min(cobs10$date), by='2 months', length=7)
lbl <- strftime(ticks, '%b')
axis(side=1, outer=TRUE, at=ticks, labels=lbl)
mtext('2010', side=1, at=x.pos, line=3)

lbl <- c(0, 2, 200, 1000, 2000, 3000, 4000)
thermals <-  splinefun(cobs10$gdd, cobs10$date)  # thermals is a function that returns the date (as an integer) for a requested value
ticks <- as.Date(thermals(lbl), origin='1970-01-01') # remember to specify an origin when converting an integer to a Date.
axis(side=3, outer=TRUE, at=ticks, labels=lbl)
mtext('Thermal units', side=3, line=15, at=x.pos)
```

[image]

*Update* I changed the `mtext` function calls in the last code block to ensure that the x-axis texts are centred on the *plotting* region, not the entire region. You might want to tweak the vertical position by changing the `line`-argument.

Comment: Thanks, I don't think I was understanding how 'at' worked, and I never would have gotten the labeling.  This was perfect.

Comment: Thanks so much @MrGumble!  I realized I was breaking the rules with so many series on a single plot, but don't we use R so that we can do exactly what we want?  Seems like some good reasons to break it up, though and your final figure is beautiful.  I'll replace my original one and send this for publication.

Comment: Cool! Glad you like it. I updated the code in the last code block a bit, so the x-axis labels ("2010" and "Thermal units" are horizontal centred on the plotting region instead of the entire window.

Comment: This question popped up on my StackOverflow today, don't know why. Did you submit the plot for publication? I'm very curious. You can contact me in private through the details on my profile.